# Prove that H is a normal subgroup if and only if, $\forall a , b \in G, ab \in$ H implies $ba\in H.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let H be a subgroup of G. Prove that H is a normal subgroup if and only if, $\forall a , b \in G, ab \in$ H implies $ba \in H.$

I don't have a problem to prove one of the implications, however, this one which I have to prove that H is normal is a bit problematic... I want a hint on how to start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** suppose $h\in H$ and $a\in G$, and set $b:=a^{-1}h$.

Comment: I got it! thanks

Comment: To anyone who doesn't see from this hint: Clearly $ab=aa^{-1}h = h \in H$. Now, $ba = a^{-1}ha$, and since $h\in H$, $a^{-1}ha=h\in H$.